# Configure DataPower for large JSON payload

Tags: ibm-datapower

Getting Error 500 with message "JSON type length exceeded" even after setting Maximum length to 5000000 bytes in Configure JSON settings in IBM DatPower Gui.  Is there any additional configure step required for IBM DataPower to cater to much larger payload?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration of  the Datapower to process large JSON payload is a 2 step process
1.  Create a new Json setting (and give it a name). Here you can specify the new length.
2. Then under XML Manager, choose both webapi and webapi-internal and under JSON settings pick your newly created setting.